# How do I get my LINQ Query to generate the SQL statement I expect?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, where-clause

I have a simple web forms in which I have 3 texboxes and a dropdownlist with a search button.

This is my code to filter the EF(4.0) context based on the input chosen out of the 4 controls:

```
string mFormId = ddlTransValueSearchFormId.SelectedItem.Text.ToString().Trim();
string mControlId = ddlTransValueSearchControlId.SelectedItem.Text.ToString().Trim();
int mTransCategoryId;
try
{
    mTransCategoryId = Int32.Parse(ddlTransValueSearchCategoryId.SelectedItem.Value.ToString());
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
string mDefaultTransValue = tbTransValueSearchDefaultValue.Text.ToString().Trim();
```

**My LINQ Query**

```
TranslationEntity efSchema = new TranslationEntity();
gvTransValues.DataSource = (from defaultValue in efSchema.TRANS_VALUES
                            .Include("TRANS_CATEGORY")
                            where (
                                mFormId == ""            ? 1 == 1 : defaultValue.FormId.Contains(mFormId)
                             && mControlId == ""         ? 1 == 1 : defaultValue.ControlId.Contains(mControlId)
                             && mTransCategoryId == -1   ? 1 == 1 : defaultValue.TransCategoryId == mTransCategoryId
                             && mDefaultTransValue == "" ? 1 == 1 : defaultValue.DefaultTranValue.Contains(mDefaultTransValue)
                             )
                         select new 
                         { 
                            TranValueId = defaultValue.TranValueId,
                            FormId = defaultValue.FormId,
                            ControlId = defaultValue.ControlId,
                            TransCategoryId = defaultValue.TransCategoryId,
                            CategoryName = defaultValue.TRANS_CATEGORY.CategoryName,
                            DefaultTranValue = defaultValue.DefaultTranValue,
                         });
gvTransValues.DataBind();
```

**The SQL statement that is generated**

Using the profiler, this is the generated SQL query:

```
declare @p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__1 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__2 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__3 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__4 int,@p__linq__5 int,@p__linq__6 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__7 nvarchar(4000)
SELECT @p__linq__0=N'',@p__linq__1=N'%%',@p__linq__2=N'',@p__linq__3=N'%%',@p__linq__4=1,@p__linq__5=1,@p__linq__6=N'cat',@p__linq__7=N'%cat%'

SELECT 
[Extent1].[TRAN_VALUE_ID] AS [TRAN_VALUE_ID], 
[Extent1].[FORM_ID] AS [FORM_ID], 
[Extent1].[CONTROL_ID] AS [CONTROL_ID], 
[Extent1].[TRANS_CATEGORY_ID] AS [TRANS_CATEGORY_ID], 
[Extent2].[CATEGORY_NAME] AS [CATEGORY_NAME], 
[Extent1].[DEFAULT_TRAN_VALUE] AS [DEFAULT_TRAN_VALUE]
FROM  [dbo].[TRANS_VALUES] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[TRANS_CATEGORY] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[TRANS_CATEGORY_ID] = [Extent2].[TRANS_CATEGORY_ID]
WHERE 
(CASE 
    WHEN (N'' = @p__linq__0) THEN cast(1 as bit) 
    WHEN (([Extent1].[FORM_ID] LIKE @p__linq__1 ESCAPE N'~') AND (N'' = @p__linq__2)) THEN cast(1 as bit) 
    WHEN (([Extent1].[CONTROL_ID] LIKE @p__linq__3 ESCAPE N'~') AND (-1 = @p__linq__4)) THEN cast(1 as bit) 
    WHEN (([Extent1].[TRANS_CATEGORY_ID] = @p__linq__5) AND (N'' = @p__linq__6)) THEN cast(1 as bit) 
    WHEN ([Extent1].[DEFAULT_TRAN_VALUE] LIKE @p__linq__7 ESCAPE N'~') THEN cast(1 as bit) 
    WHEN ( NOT ([Extent1].[DEFAULT_TRAN_VALUE] LIKE @p__linq__7 ESCAPE N'~')) THEN cast(0 as bit) 
END) = 1
```

Which is not what I want. Regardless of the parameters values, the way the script is generated by EF, is returning ALL rows from the database.

What is going wrong here?

**The SQL statement I want**

In fact, what I would need and consider to be optimal in terms of SQL server would be to get EF to generate this kind of query.

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[TRAN_VALUE_ID] AS [TRAN_VALUE_ID], 
[Extent1].[FORM_ID] AS [FORM_ID], 
[Extent1].[CONTROL_ID] AS [CONTROL_ID], 
[Extent1].[TRANS_CATEGORY_ID] AS [TRANS_CATEGORY_ID], 
[Extent2].[CATEGORY_NAME] AS [CATEGORY_NAME], 
[Extent1].[DEFAULT_TRAN_VALUE] AS [DEFAULT_TRAN_VALUE]
FROM  [dbo].[TRANS_VALUES] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[TRANS_CATEGORY] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[TRANS_CATEGORY_ID] = [Extent2].[TRANS_CATEGORY_ID]
WHERE
    ISNULL([Extent1].[FORM_ID],N'') LIKE '%' + COALESCE(@p__linq__0,[Extent1].[FORM_ID],N'') + '%'
AND ISNULL([Extent1].[CONTROL_ID],N'') LIKE '%' + COALESCE(@p__linq__1,[Extent1].[CONTROL_ID],N'') + '%'    
AND ISNULL([Extent1].[TRANS_CATEGORY_ID],-1) = COALESCE(@p__linq__2,[Extent1].[TRANS_CATEGORY_ID],-1)
AND ISNULL([Extent1].[DEFAULT_TRAN_VALUE],N'') LIKE '%' + COALESCE(@p__linq__3,[Extent1].[DEFAULT_TRAN_VALUE],N'') + '%'    
go
```

Comment: This looks like an [operator precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx) issue. Try putting parentheses around the conditions.

Comment: If EF can't automatically generate the code you want I suggest you wrap it in a stored procedure.

Comment: @Johnbot - You were right! I've added parantheses around the where clauses and now it work ok. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try writing it this way:

```
(from defaultValue in efSchema.TRANS_VALUES
 .Include("TRANS_CATEGORY")
 where (defaultValue.FormId.Contains(mFormId) || mFormId == "")
     && (defaultValue.ControlId.Contains(mControlId) || mControlId == "")
     && (defaultValue.TransCategoryId.Contains(mTransCategoryId) || mTransCategoryId == "")
     && (defaultValue.DefaultTranValue.Contains(mDefaultTransValue) || mDefaultTransValue == ""))
```

Comment: Done that, it works ok now! Thanks! .. although your conditions aren't similar to what I needed to do

Comment: Consider marking this as answered, so that your question drops off the "unanswered" queue. Thanks and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This would be a lot simpler if you constructed your query in small steps.

```
var query = efSchema.TRANS_VALUES.Include("TRANS_CATEGORY");
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mFormId))
{
    query = query.Where(defaultValue => defaultValue.FormId.Contains(mFormId));
}
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mControlId))
{
    query = query.Where(defaultValue => defaultValue.ControlId.Contains(mControlId));
}
if(mTransCategoryId != -1)
{
    query = query.Where(defaultValue => defaultValue.TransCategoryId == mTransCategoryId);
}
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mDefaultTransValue))
{
    query = query.Where(defaultValue => defaultValue.DefaultTransValue.Contains(mDefaultTransValue));
}

gvTransValues.DataSource = query.Select(defaultValue => new 
                        { 
                            TranValueId = defaultValue.TranValueId,
                            FormId = defaultValue.FormId,
                            ControlId = defaultValue.ControlId,
                            TransCategoryId = defaultValue.TransCategoryId,
                            CategoryName = defaultValue.TRANS_CATEGORY.CategoryName,
                            DefaultTranValue = defaultValue.DefaultTranValue,
                        });
```

(I think it should work like this but you might have to specify the initial type of `query` to `IQueryable<YOURTYPE>`)